# Sort-Object Name not returning order expected

Tags: powershell

I have some powershell code that gets all the files in a directory and sorts them by name. I am confused on how the sort is working and would like some clarification.

The files are listed as :

```
1_doc.pdf,
2_doc.pdf,
3_doc.pdf
.....
10_doc.pdf,
11_doc.pdf
```

When powershell does the sort, it puts them as

```
1_doc.pdf,
10_doc.pdf,
11_doc.pdf
.....
19_doc.pdf,
2_doc.pdf
```

I can see that it is looking at the first character and then looking at the second character to do the sort but do I have to rename everything to get it to sort as expected?

Comment: "do I have to rename everything to get it to sort as expected" - the short answer is "yes" because it will make everything much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there will **always be** an underscore on your file names and the files will always **start with** numbers you could use these 2 options:

```
$files = @'
1_doc.pdf
10_doc.pdf
11_doc.pdf
19_doc.pdf
2_doc.pdf
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$files | Sort-Object {[int]$_.Split('_')[0]}
$files | Sort-Object {[int][regex]::Match($_,'^\d+(?=_)').Value}
```

So the code should look something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem path/to/pdf -Filter *.pdf |
Sort-Object {[int]$_.Name.Split('_')[0]}
```

```
Get-ChildItem path/to/pdf -Filter *.pdf |
Sort-Object {[int][regex]::Match($_.Name,'^\d+(?=_)').Value}
```

---

Adding another option using `-replace`, thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

```
$files | Sort-Object {[int]($_.Name -replace '_.*')}
```

---

To explain *why does this happen when sorting files* ?

This should explain why we convert the numbers from `[string]` to `[int]` when sorting:

```
# String
'1' -lt '2' => True
'10' -lt '2' => True

# Integer
1 -lt 2 => True
10 -lt 2 => False
```

Comment: I suppose I oversimplified my question. The majority of the files are labeled as I described but there are some files at the beginning and end that are inconsistent. For instance, I have some files at the beginning that are labeled as 0A Intro.pdf, 0B tableofcontents.pdf and then some files at the end with no underscore such as 99 glossary.pdf. I am assuming the best way to fix this is to fix the file names rather than have powershell try to figure out how to sort them?

Comment: @user3870118 I think  the best approach should be to have all files with the same naming convention, there should always be a logic you can follow when writing a script and if some files have a naming convention and others do not its pretty hard to tell how you can approach the problem. hope it makes sense.

Comment: By the way, this solution seems to work Sort-Object {[int]$_.Name.Split('_')[0]} The other solution still puts 10 after 1

Comment: @user3870118 the one using `[regex]` or the one using `-replace`?

Answer (score 0):

I would just as soon rename them.

```
dir | 
rename-item -newname { [int]($_ -split '_')[0] | % tostring 00_doc\.pdf } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
      "Item: C:\Users\admin\foo\10_doc.pdf 
Destination: C:\Users\admin\foo\10_doc.pdf".

What if: performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
       "Item: C:\Users\admin\foo\1_doc.pdf 
Destination: C:\Users\admin\foo\01_doc.pdf".
```